# Scatter Matrix showing too many floating point values on graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a scatter matrix using Python but the ticks on the y-axis for the top left plot has a high amount of unnecessary digits. I'm directly plotting the graph from pandas using scatter_matrix function from pandas.plotting

Also, I am quite new to Python so sorry if this is a stupid question but I just couldn't find the right answer to fit my needs.

I've tried to use different axis formatting options using yaxis.set_major_formatter (not sure if this doesn't work because I'm plotting from pandas, but yielding no results either way), pandas.set_option to customise display.

```
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.3, figsize=(9,9), diagonal='kde')
```

```
df:         Tesla Ret  Ford Ret    GM Ret
Date                                     
2012-01-03        NaN       NaN       NaN
2012-01-04  -0.013177  0.015274  0.004751
2012-01-05  -0.021292  0.025664  0.048227
2012-01-06  -0.008481  0.010354  0.033829
2012-01-09   0.013388  0.007686 -0.003490
2012-01-10   0.013578  0.000000  0.017513
2012-01-11   0.022085  0.022881  0.052926
2012-01-12   0.000708  0.005800  0.008173
2012-01-13  -0.193274 -0.008237 -0.015403
2012-01-17   0.167179 -0.001661 -0.003705
...
```

I've tried to use:
`plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.2f}'))` and `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))` after importing the respective modulesm, to no avail.

Figure is available [here](https://i.ibb.co/yQQ8drc/scatter-matrix-plot.png)

Everything else in the figure is just as it should be, just the y-axis of the top left plot. I would like it to show one or two decimal point values like the rest of the figure.

I'd greatly appreciate any help that could fix my issue.

Thanks.

Comment: So what is the code that produces this figure? (see [mcve])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P.S: I have edited this answer based on the problem pointed out by [@ImportanceOfBeingEarnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) (thanks to him). Please read the comments below the answer to see what I mean.

The new solution is to get the displayed ticks for that particular axis and format them up to 2 decimal places.

```
new_labels = [round(float(i.get_text()), 2) for i in axes[0,0].get_yticklabels()]
axes[0,0].set_yticklabels(new_labels)
```

[image]

**OLD ANSWER** (Still kept as a history as you will see that the y-ticks in the figure generated below are not correct)

The problem is that you are using `ax` object to format the labels but `ax` returned from `scatter_matrix` is not a single axis object. It is an object containing 9 axis (3x3 subfigure). You can prove this if you plot the shape of the `axes` variable.

```
axes = scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.3, figsize=(9,9), diagonal='kde')
print (axes.shape)
# (3, 3)
```

The solution is **either** to iterate through all the axis **or** to just change the formatting for the problematic case. P.S: The figure below don't match with your's because I just used the small DataFrame you posted.

Following is how you can do it for all the y-axis

```
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

axes = scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.3, figsize=(9,9), diagonal='kde')
for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
```

[image]

**Alternatively** you can just choose a particular axis. Here your top left subfigure can be accessed using `axes[0,0]`

```
axes[0,0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
```

Comment: Yeah, but that gives you completely wrong numbers on the axis.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Hmm, that's strange. Thanks for noticing it. Any clues as in why this fails here?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: for the last two rows, it works fine but not for the first row.

Comment: The kde curve is of course in totally different units than the real data. Hence the axis tick positions and labels are faked for the top left plot to still apply to all the plots to the right of it. They use a `FixedLocator` and `FixedFormatter` for that. It's for sure not the best choice.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: When I print `axes[0,2].get_yticks()` or `axes[0,1].get_yticks()`, the scale is ok, but when I print `axes[0,0].get_yticks()`, the values are similar order as in my answer. So that means having a shared y-axis for a given row is not the correct approach?

Comment: I think having a shared y axis per row would be the better approach. That would mean to either scale the kde curve artificially, or to plot it to a twin axes instead.

Comment: I am actually right now trying to first get the yticklabels from axes[0,0] and then set them to formatted strings with 2 decimal places

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Please have a look at my edited answer. I think this way one keeps the spirit of kde and just replaces the fake y-ticks with the desired format. This seems less work as compared to rescaling and defining twin axes in my opinion

Comment: Yes, that's a good quick fix. In general, one can rethink the design of that `scatter_matrix` function.

Comment: Thanks, the new solution (at the top) here worked like a charm! Thanks both for helping!

Answer (score 2):

`pandas.scatter_matrix` suffers from an unfortunate design choice. That is, it plots the kde or histogram on the diagonal to the axes that shows the ticks for the rest of the row. This then requires to fake the ticks and labels to be fitting for the data. In the course of this a `FixedLocator` and a `FixedFormatter` are used. The format of the ticklabels is hence directly taken over from the string representation of a number.

I would propose a completely different design here. That is, the diagonal axes should stay empty, and instead twin axes are used to show the histogram or kde curve. The problem from the question can hence not occur.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def scatter_matrix(df, axes=None, **kw):
    n = df.columns.size
    diagonal = kw.pop("diagonal", "hist")

    if not axes:
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(n,n, figsize=kw.pop("figsize", None), 
                                 squeeze=False, sharex="col", sharey="row")
    else:
        flax = axes.flatten()
        fig = flax[0].figure
        assert len(flax) == n*n

    # no gaps between subplots
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)

    hist_kwds = kw.pop("hist_kwds",  {})
    density_kwds = kw.pop("density_kwds",  {})

    import itertools
    p = itertools.permutations(df.columns, r=2)
    n = itertools.permutations(np.arange(len(df.columns)), r=2)
    for (i,j), (y,x) in zip(n,p):
        axes[i,j].scatter(df[x].values, df[y].values, **kw)
        axes[i,j].tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False, 
                              bottom=False, labelbottom=False)

    diagaxes = []
    for i, c in enumerate(df.columns):

        ax = axes[i,i].twinx()
        diagaxes.append(ax)

        if diagonal == 'hist':
            ax.hist(df[c].values, **hist_kwds)

        elif diagonal in ('kde', 'density'):
            from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
            y = df[c].values
            gkde = gaussian_kde(y)
            ind = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 1000)
            ax.plot(ind, gkde.evaluate(ind), **density_kwds)

        if i!= 0:
            diagaxes[0].get_shared_y_axes().join(diagaxes[0], ax)
        ax.axis("off")


    for i,c in enumerate(df.columns):
        axes[i,i].tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False,
                               bottom=False, labelbottom=False)
        axes[i,0].set_ylabel(c)
        axes[-1,i].set_xlabel(c)
        axes[i,0].tick_params(left=True, labelleft=True)
        axes[-1,i].tick_params(bottom=True, labelbottom=True)


    return axes, diagaxes


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
axes,diagaxes = scatter_matrix(df, diagonal='kde', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this out and it does work as well but I preferred a quick fix at this problem. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Yeah, it's not really meant as a solution to your personal problem, but rather to show how one might have designed that function instead to avoid the problem. Though of course just putting the whole thing in a module in your path lets you easily use it, if desired.